# Swift - header for section does not show

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is my code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 61.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomHeaderCell") as! CustomHeaderCell
    headerCell.titleLabel.text = "user data"
    return headerCell

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 2
}
```

Unfortunately, custom header view does not show up.

However, when I use just this:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "user data"
}
```

section headers are present, what is wrong with my custom header view code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, I blindly put these functions into dataSource although they belong to tableViewDelegate

to make it work:

```
extension  UserProfileDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomHeaderCell") as! CustomHeaderCell
    headerCell.titleLabel.text = "user data"
    return headerCell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 61.0
}

}
```